# how to sort struts2jquerygrid column by default onload in client

Tags: struts2-jquery-grid

I have used `Struts2JqueryGrid` and I did client side sorting by enable `loadonce =true`, but it will work while click the column header only. I want shot a column by default on pageload or gridload.

My code is

```
<sjg:grid id="grid_vehicleedit"
    dataType="json"
    href="%{remoteurl}"
    loadonce="true"
    gridModel="vchlst"
    draggable="false" 
    hoverrows="false"
    sortable="true"
    viewrecords="true"
    sortable="true"
>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="vname" index="vname" sortable="true" title="Vehicle Name" key="true" />  
    <sjg:gridColumn name="imei" sorttype="int" sortable="true" title="Imei" index="imei"   />
    <sjg:gridColumn name="dtype" sortable="true" title="Splitter Type" width="80" index="dtype"/>

</sjg:grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these two attributes to your `<sjg:grid>` tag:

```
sortname="vname"
sortorder="asc"
```

And delete one of the occurrences of `sortable="true"`. So you should end up with:

```
<sjg:grid id="grid_vehicleedit"
    dataType="json"
    href="%{remoteurl}"
    loadonce="true"
    gridModel="vchlst"
    draggable="false" 
    hoverrows="false"
    viewrecords="true"
    sortable="true"
    sortname="vname" // determines which column you want sorted on gridload
    sortorder="asc" // default is ascending; use desc for descending
    >

    <sjg:gridColumn name="vname" index="vname" sortable="true" title="Vehicle Name" key="true" />  
    <sjg:gridColumn name="imei" index="imei" sorttype="int" sortable="true" title="Imei" />
    <sjg:gridColumn name="dtype" index="dtype" sortable="true" title="Splitter Type" width="80" />

</sjg:grid>
```